# Laravel image is not inserting

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I have made this function to store multiple form data with image and without image but it is not storing into database nor folder specified
public function submitForm(Request $request, $id) {
$request->validate($this->getFormRules($id));

```
    try {
        $form = new Submission;
        $form->form_data = $request->except('_token');
        
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $uploaded_files = [];
            foreach ($request->file('file') as $key => $file) {
                if ($file->isValid()) {
                    $newFileName = $key . '_' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    // Correct usage: store([folder], [disk])
                    $path = $file->store('public/img'); // No need to specify new file name here
                    $uploaded_files[$key] = $path;
                } else {
                    return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid file uploaded.'], 400);
                }
            }
            $form->form_data['uploaded_files'] = $uploaded_files;
        }
        
        $form->submitted_by = auth()->id();
        $form->form_id = $id; 
        $form->save();
        
        Toastr::success('Form submitted successfully.', 'Success');
        return redirect()->back();
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        \DB::rollback();
        Toastr::error('Failed to submit form.', 'Error');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

image is not storing into database nor folder

Comment: `$form->form_data['uploaded_files'] = $uploaded_files;` looks like an Array to String conversion? Have you checked whether an exception is being caught by your catch block? You can do this easily by adding `dd($e);` to it